# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list при анимировании

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("input").click(function(){
        $('input, textarea').placeholder().animate(left: '250px');
    });
});
```

Comment: Во-первых, на русском, плиз, а во вторых, `left: '250px'` - не валидный параметр

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.animate({left: '250px'}); // пропущены фигурные скобки
```